# How to run ScraPy Spiders in Play, Java/Scala environment?

Tags: scala, playframework, scrapy

For current project I made a Web API in Scala, however I need to scrape +- 70 urls on each user request. How can I do this with Scrapy while using Scala/Java? Are there other ways to do this?

Comment: What have already tried by yourself? Code? Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing a background task using an Actor. Although one way to do this is by scheduling something to occur [2](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScheduledTasks#Scheduling-asynchronous-tasks) every N seconds, using an Actor adds a queue (mailbox). A queue is important so you don't overload the server.

You can have a controller like this [1](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAkka#The-application-actor-system):

```
case object StartScraping

class Scraper extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case StartScraping =>
      // do the scraping!
  }
}

class MyController (@Named("scraper-actor") configuredActor: ActorRef) {
  def get = Action {
    configuredActor ! StartScraping
  }
}
```

You haven't provided much detail in terms of specifications, but this is a good start that will work for many purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the answer I was looking for!